# What's the meaning of $544/119 = 4 + 68/119$?

Tags: notation

> The Art Of Computer Programming Third Edition, page 4

While explaining Euclid's Greatest Common Divisor algorithm for the numbers $544$ and $119$, Knuth calculates the remainder of $544/119$ which is $68$ using: $544/119 = 4 + 68/119$. I don't understand this notation. What does $=$ mean in this case, mathematical assignment)? And how do $4$ and $68$ occur? Obviously the direct division $544/119$ gives the remainder $68$ but that's not what Knuth does.

Comment: As rational numbers $\frac{544}{119}=4+\frac{68}{119}$.

Comment: $544 = 4*119 + 68$. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: $\frac{544}{119} =  \frac{476}{119} + \frac{68}{119} = 4  + \frac{68}{119}$

Comment: @nbubis Thanks, my math are rusted and I couldn't see the relation. Can you add it as an answer so that I can accept/upvote it?